# Modelling a compound random variable from a Poisson process?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

One other question I came across that I didn't quite understand.

> The number of forks that enter the sink follows a Poisson process with rate $λ= 200$ per month. Each fork which enters the sink has probability $p$ of smashing into pieces, otherwise it remains intact. Assume that each fork smashes upon impact or not after entering the sink independently of everything else.
>
> Suppose that the mass of any fork that smashes in the sink is independently drawn from an Exponential distribution with mean $10$ g. Let $Y$ be the total mass of forks that smash upon impact in the sink in a year. Calculate the mean and variance of $Y$. (Assume that one year equals exactly 12 months)

This is almost an extension of my last question, which I found in my text, that I'm trying to do for practice.

**My thinking** is that I should be using the compound random variable formula, and that I should be letting $X_{i}$ be the mass of any given fork which smashes in the sink. But I'm not really sure how I should explicitly express my problem, nor how to find the distribution for $Y$ in order to calculate the mean/variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ represent the number of forks  that enter the sink in a year.

$$X \sim \text{Poi}(2400) $$

$Z$ represent the number of smashed forks in a year.

$$X \sim \text{Poi}( 2400 p) $$

$Y$ represent the mass of smashed forks in a year.

$$Y = E_1 + \ldots + E_Z  $$

where $E_i$ is are independent exponential random variable of mean $10$ and variance $100$.

Therefore 
$$E(Y) = E(Z E_1) = E(Z) E(E_1) = 24000 p   $$

and $$Var(Y) = E(Z^2 E_1^2) - E(Z E_1)^2 = ((2400p)^2 + 2400p)110 - (24000 p)^2 $$